# UIView animation is not working properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I have a `UIViewController` with an animated `UIBarButtonItem` on the toolbar.

Pressing another `UIButton` in order to push the second `UIViewController` (where the animated button doesn't exist) and popping it, the animations works as expected.

But if I try to move the app in background and restore it, I still see the animation there, but not anymore if I try to push and pop.

Furthermore I added the same animated button in the view of the first `UIViewController`, and the animation stopped working by pressing push/pop without going in background.

In the code of the `UIButton`, I added this in order to manage the animation during transition to background and foreground:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationDidEnterBackground) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationWillEnterForeground) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];

...

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground
{
    [self.spinner.layer removeAllAnimations];
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground
{
    [self createAnimation];
}

- (void)createAnimation
{
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];

    [animation setFromValue:@(0)];
    [animation setToValue:@(DegreesToRadians(359))];
    [animation setDuration:0.4];
    [animation setRepeatCount:MAXFLOAT];
    [self.spinner.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:animation.keyPath];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

problem solved (I don't know if it's the best way)

```
- (void)didMoveToWindow
{
    [super didMoveToWindow];
    if (self.window != nil) {
         [self createAnimation];
    }
}
```

Basically, it looks that when the view is disappearing (because of a push in this case) all the animations are removed automatically. Because of this, it's needed to recreate them once the view is showed again.